# Different coords by LocationListener VS FusedLocation

Tags: android, floating-point-precision, locationlistener, fusedlocationproviderapi

I noticed that *LocationListener* and *FusedLocation* (used with GPS, by PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY) retrieve different coordinates.

*LocationListener* get back latitude with **8 decimals**, instead *FusedLocation* get back latitude with **7 or sometimes 6 decimal**: decimals seems rounded resulting in less precision.

Tested on my Moto X/KitKat with PlayServices:6.1.11

Anyone knows why? There's a way to use FusedLocation without no rounded results?

Thanks.

EDIT The accuracy retrieved by getAccuracy is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why each would provide a different number of decimal places, but I also would not use the number of decimal places as an indication of accuracy.

Location objects have a `hasAccuracy()` method and a `getAccuracy()` method .  These are what you should be using to determine the accuracy of the location returned by either service.

Here is the link to the location class

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html

Comment: I forgot to specify it but the accuracy is of course the same.